# How to show a component inside Angular Material dialog component?

Tags: angular, typescript, c3.js

I would like to show parentComponent that generating c3 charts, inside DialogModalComponent. I can see the text from parentComponent when I open the dialog, but it's not showing the c3 Chart. How can I show the c3 chart that's been created in parent component to show in Dialog ModalComponent?

Comment: Your stackblitz app is broken.. `ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ParentComponent -> MatDialog]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ParentComponent -> MatDialog]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[ParentComponent -> MatDialog]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ParentComponent -> MatDialog]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!`

Comment: Import MatDialog module, then inject dialog service in your ParentComponent, have your C3 chart component added as an Entry component, and then you can use injected dialog service to perform actions on Mat Dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your stackblitz.
At your app.module change to:

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Now the real question. In your parent component, when generating your graphic you are selecting the div with an id as seen here:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#barChart',
  ...
}
```

The problem is: when reusing this component, the c3 generator will try to find an id `barChart` in you html. Turns out it is find the first one that is already showing up and not the new one inside the modal.
To fix this, I think the `@ViewChild` can help:

In parent.component.html:
    `<div #barChart></div>`

And in parent.component.ts:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('barChart') barChart:ElementRef;
  ...
  createChart(){
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: this.barChart.nativeElement,
    ...
  }
```

This way you component always will find it's own barChart

Comment: I changed it to "import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';" Now the app is working, but on click to the button it's not showing the c3 Chart in the dialog

Comment: @Avocado Updated

Answer (score 0):

**No provider for MatDialog!**

Please check your **app.module.ts** the import statement is wrong.

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';
```

> Please check the official documentation of [Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api) Material design
>
> `import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';`

and in your component file

```
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

Rest of the connectivity is fine . Hope this will solve your problem
Cheers!

Comment: Dialog works fine. I am having problem showing parent component that generates c3 Chart,  inside dialog.